# Interface design in Foodspotting

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

On the app Foodspotting, you have a scrolling view that has two elements:

1) An image.

2) Some information below it.

Like this:

[image]

When you start scrolling down, the behaviour is not natural of a `UITableView`, or at least I am not understanding it. The below view start's going up and overlapping the `UIImageView` above it:

[image]

And finally:

[image]

**What I have tried:**

1) Using the first four cells without content and invisible and finally an `UIImageView` as subView of the `UITableView`

2) The same as above but using the `UIImageView` as subView of the root view and below the `UITableView`.

3) Mixing the `UITableView` and a `UIScrollView` with an `UIImageView` inside the UIScrollView.

So my question, how was this achieved?

---

**Edit 1.0**

If someone want to try, you can check the project [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ytgbbyf1frfymws/b_P3ESfh9q).

Comment: Love the inclusion of the project download. Very cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like a `UIViewController` with a `UIImageView` on the bottom.

Then a `UITableView` on top of that (grouped table view) with a transparent background.

The header height is then set to almost the height of the entire view.  With a button (or whatever that is) near the bottom of the header.

You could access the `scrollView:didScroll` to adjust the position of the UIImageView in the background (it looks like the center point of the image is always half way down the visible part of the header.

```
bgImageView.center = CGPointMake(0, (bgImageView.frame.size.height - scrollView.offset.y) * 0.5);
```

or something like that.

Obviously the image view would not move any further down than the top so you'd have to catch that somehow.

Comment: It was more to check how it was done than to actually apply. The `scrollView:didScroll` was the key.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like an image view is the background view of the table (so it won't scroll), a large transparent view as the table header (possibly with that first button in it, or that could be a transparent cell) then opaque cells for the remaining content.

And that risotto is far too wet. 0 stars, more like rice soup.